# Not receiving emails from gmail users from the contact form on my site

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I have a contact form made with PHPMailer, where users enter their data. If the email field, enter an email with gmail, I do not receive this email, not even in the spam folder. I set the ReplyTo but neither works. I'm assuming it can be blocked by the server.

**PHP:**

```
require_once('../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

/*datos personales*/
$name       = strip_tags(trim($_POST['nombre']));
$name       = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
$provincia  = $_POST['provincia'];
$localidad  = strip_tags(trim($_POST['localidad']));
$email      = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$prefijo    = strip_tags(trim($_POST['prefijo']));
$sufijo     = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefono']));
$telefono   = $prefijo.' - '.$sufijo;


if ( $marca == 'default' || $modelo == 'default' || $cilin == 'default' || $valvulas == 'default' || $anio == 'default' || $autonomia == 'default') {            
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Porfavor, corrobore que no falte ningún dato del vehículo.";
    exit;
} else if ( $provincia == 'default' ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Porfavor, eliga una provincia.";
    exit;
} else if ( $pago == 'default' ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Porfavor, eliga un método de pago.";
    exit;
} else if (empty($name) || empty($localidad) || empty($prefijo) | empty($telefono)) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Porfavor, complete los campos que estan en blanco.";
    exit;
}

$recipient = "info@energygnc.com.ar";

$subject = "[Cotizador EnergyGNC] Solicitud de cotización por $name en energygnc.com.ar";
// Build the email content.
$email_content = "Solicitud de cotización realizada por: $name ($email)<br><br>";
$email_content .= "Datos del vehículo:<br>Marca: $marca $modelo modelo $anio<br>";
$email_content .= "Motor: $cilin - $valvulas<br>";
$email_content .= "Autonomia deseada: $autonomia<br><br>";
$email_content .= "Datos del cliente:<br>Nombre: $name<br>Email: $email<br>Telefono: $telefono<br>";
$email_content .= "Provincia: $provincia<br>Localidad: $localidad.<br>";
$email_content .= "Metodo de pago que me interesa: $pago";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->AddAddress($recipient);
$mail->Subject = '[Cotizador EnergyGNC] Solicitud de cotización por '.$name.' en energygnc.com.ar'; 
$mail->Body = $email_content;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Gracias por contactarse con nosotros.";
}
```

Comment: You need to check your mail server logs to find out what's happening.

Comment: `Nov 27 16:27:25 lupine postfix/smtp[18189]: A095F61009:
to=<produccion@dev.criterionet.com>,
relay=irv-shared-relay1.dreamhost.com[64.90.62.20]:25, delay=0.03,
delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host
irv-shared-relay1.dreamhost.com[64.90.62.20] said: 550 5.7.1 Sender
domain not allowed. Please read: http://dhurl.org/20b (in reply to end of
DATA command))` @Synchro

Comment: @Synchro Apparently DreamHost blocking this. But if I set `AddAddress(webmaster@domaindreamhost.com)` and `AddReplyTo(user@gmail.com)`. For the answer is taking the value of `AddAdress`.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely GMail uses a [Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework). It means that your mail provider will check that your server (that is sending the mail on behalf of gmail) was allowed by Google to send mails with their domain.

You'd rather put the email of the sender in the content of your mail and use another address in the From field.

Comment: My hosting is Dreamhost. And the form is addressed to your webmail, (info@domain.com). The optimal for me (and my client) would be that when you click on responding already email the user who filled the form set.

Comment: Some mail providers check only for the `From` field of the email, some others check also the `Reply To` field but it's not automatic. Did you try putting the gmail address only on the  `Reply To` but not as the sender of your mail ?

Comment: if I did, but it takes `setFrom` email response. I also tried putting `AddReplyTo` before `setFrom` as I saw in a solution of another post, but neither works with gmail

Comment: Well the only thing left is to not use the gmail address in the From and the Reply to fields, but instead put it in the content, with a mailto link on it to have a quick way to respond.

Comment: Servers will be checking the envelope sender first. Set that in Phpmailer using the `Sender` property. Do not put an address that's not related to the sending server in the from address.