# Bootstrap CSS contact form not getting emails from certain emails

Tags: gmail, contact-form

I use a bootstrap form I got some years ago on a number of sites. Recently, it seems if the person sending the message uses gmail...it does not get received.

The receiver can use gmail without a problem.

Current example: [text](https://sandeelovas.com/contact/)

I have tried a range of different emails in the receiver, using my domain emails and gmail accounts and then tested sending emails using the contact form from real and fake addresses. I will receive all the emails except the ones from a gmail account (real or fake).

I don't understand how the sender's email can be the issue.

The issue seems to be the same as this post: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176728/not-receiving-emails-from-gmail-users-from-the-contact-form-on-my-site) - I also use Dreamhost.

But I don't understand what the answers mean here, and it didn't seem to resolve the issue.